# Retorno em métodos

Tags: php

Colegas.

Tenho uma classe onde meus métodos que contém argumentos, porém não possuem retorno, costumo colocar no final o seguinte código:

```
public function metodoRetorno($valor) {
    // ...
    return true;
}
```

Mas nos métodos que não possuem argumentos ( vazios ) ex.:

```
public function metodoVazio() {
    // ...
}
```

... não coloco nenhum tipo de retorno. Algum tempo atrás, se não me engano, aprendi que é aconselhado colocar o retorno como verdadeiro, porém não consigo me lembrar se métodos que não possuem argumentos usam isso.

Esta lógica está correta?

Comment: Obrigado a todos pelas explicações.

Answer (score 4):

Os parâmetros são uma coisa e o retorno é outra coisa.

Imagine que cada método representa um trabalho a ser realizado. Os parâmetros são aquilo que é necessário para que o trabalho possa ser realizado (além daquilo que já é disponível por meio do `$this`). O retorno é o resultado que o método dá para quem o chamou.

Para exemplificar isso de uma forma bem simples e didática, imagine alguns probleminhas:

---

1. Você vai a padaria para comprar pão. Ao chegar na padaria, eis o que você precisa:

   - Saber o número de pães que você vai comprar.
   - Ter dinheiro ou cartão ou cheque ou algum outro meio de pagamento.

   E eis o que você trás como resultado:

   - Uma sacola de pães.

   Desta forma, vamos supor que eu modelasse a função `comprarPaes`:

   ```
   public function comprarPaes($numeroDePaes, $meioDePagamento) {
       // ...
       return $sacola;
   }
   ```

   Ou seja, esta função tem dois parâmetros e tem um retorno.

---

2. Você vai levar o lixo para fora. Eis o que você precisa:

   - Saber aonde está o lixo.
   - Saber aonde está a lixeira.

   Eu poderia modelar essa função mais ou menos assim:

   ```
   public function botarLixoPraFora($lixo, $lixeira) {
       $lixo->embalar();
       sairParaRua();
       $lixeira->colocarLixo($lixo);
   }
   ```

   E observe que essa função, apesar de ter dois parâmetros, não tem nenhum retorno. Ela simplesmente executa uma tarefa e uma vez pronta, nenhum resultado especial é necessário além da execução da tarefa em si.

---

3. O dólar está muito instável nos últimos dias e você quer saber a cotação de hoje:

   ```
   public function buscarCotacaoDoDolar() {
       // ...
       return $cotacao;
   }
   ```

   E essa função, embora não tenha nenhum parâmetro, tem um tipo de retorno.

---

4. Você vai ligar o rádio para ouvir música:

   ```
   public function ouvirMusica() {
       $radio = localizarRadio();
       $radio->ligar();
       $radio->sintonizarAondeTemUmaMusicaLegal();
   }
   ```

   E essa função, não tem nenhum parâmetro e nenhum tipo de retorno. Consiste em uma tarefa a ser feita aonde nada precisa ser retornado, nenhum dado especial (parâmetro) é necessário para executar a tarefa e nenhum resultado especial é necessário além da execução da tarefa em si.

---

Enfim, observe as quatro combinações que temos, todas perfeitamente válidas:

- Com parâmetros e com retorno.
- Com parâmetros e sem retorno.
- Sem parâmetros e com retorno.
- Sem parâmetros e sem retorno.

Ou seja, não existe nenhuma regra que diz que se não há retorno então não deve ter parâmetros e nem o contrário.

Quando uma função não puder executar a tarefa que se dispõe, ou falhar em executá-la, o mecanismo adequado a se utilizar é o tratamento de exceções. Por exemplo:

```
public function comprarPaes($numeroDePaes, $meioDePagamento) {
    $padaria = irAPadaria();
    if (!$padaria->estaAberta()) {
        throw new Exception("A padaria não está aberta. Não dá para comprar pão.");
    }
    $padaria->irAteOBalcao();
    $atendente = $padaria->esperarAtendente();
    $atendente->pedirPaes($numeroDePaes);
    try {
        $atendente->realizarPagamento($meioDePagamento);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // Ocorreu um erro com o pagamento.
        // Pode ser que não tenha dinheiro suficiente
        // ou o cartão pode estar fora da validade,
        // ou algum outro problema desse tipo.
        throw new Exception("Problema no pagamento: " . $e->getMessage());
    }
    $sacola = $atendente->receberSacola();
    return $sacola;
}
```

Neste caso, observe que nos pontos aonde algo dá errado que impossibilita que a tarefa possa ser completada, uma exceção é lançada. Não é bom retornar `true` se deu certo e `false` se não deu, pois isto tende a ser confuso e a ideia do tratamento de exceções surgiu exatamente para que não seja necessário fazer-se este tipo de coisa. Além disso, a exceção pode transportar muito mais informações sobre o erro do que um simples `true` ou `false`.

Note também que a função `comprarPaes` tem retorno e parâmetros, e dentro dela é usada a `realizarPagamento` que tem parâmetro mas não tem retorno, a `esperarAtendente` que tem retorno e não tem parâmetros e a `irAteOBalcao` que não tem nem retorno e nem parâmetros. Enfim, podemos usar as quatro combinações possíveis juntamente com o tratamento de exceções.

Answer (score 3):

Os argumentos dos métodos ou funções não definem ou determinam o tipo de retorno.

As funções e métodos que não possuem retorno, são chamadas de funções de "retorno nulo" ou "void return".

Exemplo

```
function Foo(){
    $r = 1 + 1;
}
```

Essa função não possui um retorno. Logo, o que a função retorna é um `NULL`, pois no PHP, um retorno não definido é retornado como `NULL`: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php

No PHPDocs ou PHP-Fig, não há especificações que "obrigue" a definição do retorno. Talvez porque o PHP já retorna automaticamente como nulo quando não há definição.

Veja também que mesmo invocando `echo` ou `print`, sem definir o `return`, a funbção ainda retornará como `NULL`.

```
function Foo(){
    $r = 1 + 1;
    echo 'a';
}

var_dump(Foo());
```

Answer (score 2):

Não deveria existir nenhuma relação entre os argumentos que o método aceita, e o retorno que ele deveria passar.

Se um método não retorna nenhum valor, seu retorno é entendido como *void* (vazio).

Geralmente deveríamos retornar booleanos (`true` ou `false`) em métodos que executam algum bloco de código, e nesse caso o booleano serviria para dar um *feedback* em relação ao que foi feito no método (por exemplo, se o código foi executado com sucesso ou não).

Em relação a não retornar nada em funções que não aceitam argumentos, acho que isso faz até algum sentido em métodos de classe que "preparam" as propriedades para algum método posterior (por exemplo, construtores). Pode também fazer sentido em métodos que fazem parte de algum *design pattern* (por exemplo, o *template method*) mas, novamente, acho que depende muito de caso para caso.